# Hundreds of excel lookup values to MySQL inserts online?

Tags: sql, mysql, excel

I have hundreds of excel documents which have lookup values for all the lookup tables that I am giving to my developers. some are small and some are super huge like world cities. Either i can send them the xls file and let them import it into the DB but I prefer to send them the SQL inserts in a text file so they can just execute it and save time to load all the data.

Now I dont have any MySQL environment setup as i dont do development so the question is how do i convert the various colunms of lookup values on each excel tab into insert statements to load in? Are there any online tools that can read the xls and create sql inserts? I dont want to manually do it, the city table itself will take me a whole week if i put in 12 hours a day each day of the week to manually create the inserts for all the rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within Excel, save your spreadsheets as CSV (comma separated values) files. Your developers will be able to load them into MySQL directly using [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html). If they create a table with columns that match the CSV columns, then your developers can import them with the following SQL command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_name.csv'
INTO TABLE tbl_name
FIELDS
    TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES
    TERMINATED BY '\r\n' -- or '\n' if you are on unix or '\r' if you are on mac
IGNORE 1 LINES -- if you want to skip over the column headings
```